# What is this mail icon on the bottom right of a new xml layout in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have not been on studio in a bit and when I made a new layout theres some small mail icon in the bottom right. I cant seem to find the code for it and am curious as to what it does/how to get rid of it-

Heres a screenshot of what im talking about-

[image]

the small mail icon in the bottom right is what im talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for this will be in `activity_main.xml`. It is just part of the new templates that came with Android Studio 1.4.

To remove this icon, go into `activity_main.xml` and remove the `android:src` attribute of the `FloatingActionButton`, or change it to the drawable you'd rather use.